# Как использовать pygost?

Tags: python, криптография

Мне необходимо использовать криптографический алгоритм - ГОСТ Р 34.10-2001. Установил библиотеку pygost. А примеров использования pygost не могу найти.

Comment: [На pypi](https://pypi.org/project/pygost/) же есть.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов , там пример для 34.10-2012, а в ссылке предложенной там же, 34.10-2001, заменен на 34.10-2012

Comment: используйте openssl с плагином или криптопро